# PHPUnit - assert that two strings are equal and they are

Tags: phpunit, selenium-rc

I'm using selenium RC with PHPunit and i have this problem. I'm trying to do assertEqual but this is the result:

```
Failed asserting that two strings are equal.
--- Expected
+++ Actual
@@ @@
 abc
 def
```

The step line:

```
$this->assertEquals("abc\ndef", $this->getValue("text"));
```

and "text" is "abc\ndef".

In firefox it's working ok. The problem is only with IE. In the result he doesn't tell me what is not equal..

Answer (score 5):

There's most likely a carriage return (`\r`) in there which PHPUnit's string diff output isn't displaying. Use `addslashes()` or `serialize()` to display the hidden characters.

```
$this->assertEquals(addslashes("abc\ndef"), addslashes($this->getValue("text")));
```

Answer (score 2):

I add an answer for the people that arrive here with Google.
You can do like that too:

```
$this->assertEquals(preg_split('/\r\n|\r|\n/', "abc\ndef"), preg_split('/\r\n|\r|\n/', $this->getValue("text")));
```

or

```
// Note the return line in the PHP file without any space at the begining
$this->assertEquals(preg_split('/\r\n|\r|\n/', 'abc
def'), preg_split('/\r\n|\r|\n/', $this->getValue("text")));
```